# Sagepay session keys vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, opayo

I am just starting the task of using SagePay drop in forms to replace the current payment process on our website. The first part of the page load is to generate a session key from Sagepay (this lasts 400 seconds). The curl command example that they give on their website works using using our API Key & Password as shown below:-

```
curl https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/merchant-session-keys \
-H "Authorization: Basic aEpZeHN3N0hMYmo0MGNCOHkxodUo4RzU0TzZyRHBVWHZFNmhZRHJyaWE6bzJpSFNyRnliWU1acG1XT1FNdWhzWFA1MlY0ZkJ0cHVTRHNocktEU1dzQlkxT2lONmh3ZDlLYjEyejRqNVVzNXU="  \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d '{
  "vendorName": "ourvendorname"
}'
```

The basic authorisation that is sent above is a base64encode of apikey:apipassword. (the above is just an example).

So they have also a php example, however I am trying to accomplish this in vb.net. Looking at a couple of sites I have cobbled together the below:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<script runat="server">

Sub Page_Load()


    Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest
    Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse
    Dim myData As String = "{""vendorName"": ""ourvendorname""}"


    'Response.Write(myData)


    myReq = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://pi-live.sagepay.com/api/v1/merchant-session-keys")
    myReq.Method = "POST"
    myReq.ContentType = "application/json"
    myReq.Headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ourapikey:ourapipassword")))
    myReq.GetRequestStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData).Count)

    myResp = myReq.GetResponse
    Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
    Dim myText As String
    myText = myreader.ReadToEnd


End Sub

</script
```

This however fails with the following :-

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
```

Compiler Error Message: `BC30456: 'Count' is not a member of 'System.Array'.`

Source Error:

```
Line 24:    myReq.ContentType = "application/json"
Line 25:    myReq.Headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("base64encodedversionofapikey:apipassword")))
Line 26:    myReq.GetRequestStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData).Count)
Line 27:    
Line 28:    myResp = myReq.GetResponse

Source File: C:\xxxxxxx\new.aspx    Line: 26
```

I have read that yes .count is not a member of system.array under .net 2.0 and that it is under 3.5, I have changed the application pool to .net 4.0 but still no dice. I have also read if you import system.linq this will resolve the error, still same error. I lastly read that using .length instead of .count is what is needed however the web page just hangs and times out without an error. I have tried putting a value to replace the end value of the bytestream (lower than the actual length) still just hangs.

I am out of ideas, so have come here....

I have output to the console the variable mydata and it looks correctly formatted as per their website.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: No, `Count` was never a member of `Array`. It's isn't now either. [Count()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a *LINQ function*. The correct property is `.Length`. Use [Option Strict](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic-net-and-in-visual-ba) to catch such errors during compilation

Comment: If your web application hangs, debug it. Use proper exception handling to find and log problems. Don't look for obscure bugs in the runtime. And **don't put the application code in the page**. `Page_Load` belongs in the code-behind file if you use the old Webforms stack. It's been replaced by the controller constructor in the newer ASP.NET MVC stack. and the PageModel costructor in the latest Razor Pages stack

Comment: Hi, many thanks for responding. I was really just trying to do a proof of concept for the starting block of the project (obtaining session keys), would the fact that i was importing system.linq not have allowed .count to function? I have seem examples similar to this where people are not getting the error that I am getting using .count.

Comment: There is no Count property. There is no Count property.

Comment: OK so I took your advice, I through this into a single page webforms project in VS2017. The code unchanged (and with .count) works perfectly and returns the valid session key from Sagepay API - Dont get that ???

Comment: and that is with code behind